# Add another hour when running python script on 2nd iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, range, timedelta

I have a Python script that uses the datetime, timedelta, and selenium modules.
The script goes to a website, enters the current time (using datetime), and adds the number that the user inputted onto the current time (using timedelta).

I also have a loop going. But I want to make sure that when the script is on its 2nd loop, it will add double the user input.

(E.G: **user enters a 2**, the script will enter a 2 onto the current time's hour. Then loops again, but this time adds a 4 to the current time's hour.)

Does anyone know how I could implement this idea? It will be very useful for my project, thanks.

Code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

hr_input = int(input('how many hours to add?: ')
amount_loops = int(input('how many times to loop?: ')

for i in range(amount_loops):
        time.sleep(2)
        adding = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=int(hr_input))).strftime("%H:%M")
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="input-1"]/input'))).send_keys(adding + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want to multiply it by 2 each time, you can use the i variable and multiply the by 2**i

1. so first time 2**0 = 1 so no effect
2. second time 2**1 = 2 so times 2
3. third time 2**2 = 4 etc. etc.

i.e

```
    adding = (datetime.now() + timedelta( hours=2**i*int(hr_input) )).strftime("%H:%M")
```

Comment: What about adding instead of multiplying?

Comment: @Daneul what do you mean by that? Adding how many times to what on which iteration?

Comment: I mean that instead of multiplying like your answer, adding 2 hours on the 5th iteration to make it 7 etc.

Comment: Can u explain how you reached 7 exactly because 2*5 = 10

Comment: I didn't actually, that was an example of what I mean by my comment. Your answer works well and I used it perfectly, but I'm thinking if it's possible to add instead. So if I wanted to make it add 2 onto the iteration in the future, then I would want 2 hours to be added to the 5th iteration to make 7.